# How can I detect when video finished playing react?

Tags: reactjs

Since React uses lifecycle methods and the virtual dom how can I detect when my video has finished playing. I found another question like this on stackoverflow that suggested to use componentWillUnmount but there's no point at which I remove the video from the dom, so componentWillUnmount won't get fired...

How can I detect when video finished playing react?

Answer (score 14):

You could also use the `onEnded` media event on the video element. This feature has been supported since 2015; it's much easier to work with and can be used in functional components.

```
const myCallback = () => (console.log('Video has ended'));

<video autoplay onEnded={() => myCallback()}>
    <source src={[yourVideoURL]} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Also make sure `loop` is not `true` on the video element, because then, the onEnded event will never be fired.**

More information here:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`ref` callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to obtain a reference to the `<video` DOM element when it mounts.

```
<video ref={el => this.videoElement = el}></video>
```

Combine that with [`componentDidMount()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) to add an event listener to the video element. The [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) is what you're looking for.

> The ended event is fired when playback or streaming has stopped
>   because the end of the media was reached or because no further data is
>   available.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.videoElement.addEventListener("ended", myCallback);
}
```

Remember to remove the event listener when your component will unmount, otherwise you'll be left with a dangling event listener on an element that doesn't exist anymore!

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.videoElement.removeEventListener("ended", myCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: It took me a while to figure this out, but `onEnded` is not triggered the you also have the `loop` attribute as well.
Which make sense, but in my case I needed both. So I ended up removing the loop and start it again in the onEnded function.